# How does sizeof work for different data types when added and calculated?

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int i = 20;
    char c = 97;
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sizeof(i), sizeof(c), sizeof(c + i));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
2, 1, 4
```

According to me it should be

```
2, 1, 2
```

because `char + short int` is `short int` and size of `short int` is `2`.

Comment: This duplicate really looks *very* similar. It looks that this is some sort of assignment, and your teacher is using the same material as last year :) Please, first look into your course if you can't find an answer and think about it. Only then go to SO, but first search for the things that intrigue you.

Comment: I searched a lot, but was unable to find it. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to C standard [integral promotion rules](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/language_ref/cplr066.html), the type of the expression `c + i` will be `int`, that's why you're getting the equivalent of `sizeof (int)`, i.e. `4`.

> When different arithmetic types are used as operands in certain types of expressions, standard conversions known as usual arithmetic conversions are applied. These conversions are applied according to the rank of the arithmetic type: the operand with a type of lower rank is converted to the type of the operand with a higher rank. This is known as integral or floating point promotion.

[image]

Besides this, according to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than `int` as arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied. So you will get `4` even for `sizeof(c+c)`.

And you can find the following information from [This International Standard - Programming languages — C, Section 6.3.1.1, Clause 2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> [...] If an intcan represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned
>   int. These are called the integer promotions. The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~operators, and to both operands of the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.) [...]

Comment: As I understand your explanation and the table, the `char` would be promoted to `short int`, so why is `sizeof(c+i) = 4` and not `2`? And why is `sizeof(c+c) = 4`?

Comment: @MartinR First forget about the sizeof and the final value. Just look at the type the final value has. `char + short int = int`  `int + int = int`

Comment: @self.: Yes, but I cannot see from this answer why `char + short int = int`.

Comment: @MartinR the only common type of char and short int is int. char cannot be converted to short int according to the implicit conversion rules.

Comment: @self.: Yes, that is what I always thought. But I cannot find that information in the above answer or in the table. (That may be my fault.)

Comment: @MartinR Found it. char and short int are treated as an int in arithmetic operations.

Comment: @self.: OK, thanks for the reference. - And in this moment the answer has been updated to include that information!

Comment: @self+MartinR Thanks for the discussion. Updated the answer.

Comment: See also the [online C2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.3.1.1, clause 2, and footnote 58.

Comment: @JohnBode Great reference, added to the answer. Thanks.